# Hive File does not exist - Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' does not work

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, airflow, hdfs

**Error:**

> File does not exist: hdfs://warehouse/hive/my_db.db/my_table/26-01_29_data.0.parq
>
> It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.

Hi everyone,

as you can see in the above, I have an error in Hive table.

When I controlled, I found that the file really does not exist. But names of files are renaming when every Airflow run is failed. I added a "Refresh Table" command to my Spark script and also refreshed table in Impala. But it does not work.

Comment: Did you try the command "msck repair table table-name".

Comment: Yes  I tried this command in Hive. same error still.